# Fails using twice the MOJO's exec-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

I try to run twice the MOJO's exec-maven-plugin but it complains that the mainClass is not set. With this my.Main I want to generate couple of files and they must be finisched befor the compilation phase. What I am doing wrong? The mainClass is set for both executions, with the correct arguments.

My pom.xml contains this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ABC_FALSE</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-abc</argument>
                    <argument>false</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>ABC_TRUE</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-abc</argument>
                    <argument>true</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After running

```
mvn exec:java
```

I get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) on project exec-generation: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java are missing or invalid.
```

Best regards,
SK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>exucute_the_executable_jar_1</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>the.Main</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>a</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>exucute_the_executable_jar_2</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>the.Main</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>b</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

by invoking the maven with this command:

```
mvn package
```

OK, I used it in the **generate-resources** phase, but you can change it.

Best regards,
grafl